# Poiseuille’s Law and viscosity type

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

Is kinematic or dynamic viscosity meant to be used in Poiseuille’s Law? What's the reason behind this?

I have seen contradicting information online and they seem to use the same sign.

Comment: In poiseuille's law, dynamic viscosity is the required parameter.

Comment: They have different units so you could use dimensional analysis to find out

Comment: @nluigi I have tried this but sources were contradicting here too

Comment: @TNTCookie I don't see how it can contradict with dimensional analysis; kinematic viscosity is in $m^2/s$ and kinematic viscosity in $Pa.s$ which are completely different units. Please edit your question with more info